# SPARK JDBC Connection Reuse for many Queries Executed

Tags: apache-spark

Borrowing from SO `26634853`, then the following questions :

Using an **IMPALA** connection like this is a one-shot set up :

```
val JDBCDriver = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver"
val ConnectionURL = "jdbc:impala://url.server.net:21050/default;auth=noSasl"

Class.forName(JDBCDriver).newInstance
val con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL)
val stmt = con.createStatement()
val rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)

val resultSetList = Iterator.continually((rs.next(), rs)).takeWhile(_._1).map(r => {
getRowFromResultSet(r._2) // (ResultSet) => (spark.sql.Row)
}).toList

sc.parallelize(resultSetList)
```

What if I need to put a `loop` around the `con.createStatement()` and associated code thereunder with some logic and execute it say, some, `5000` times?

1. Referring to the db connection overhead discussions with map vs. mapPartitions, would I, in this case, incur `5000` x the cost of the connection, or is it re-usable the way it is done here? From documentation on SCALA JDBC it looks like it can be reused.

My thinking is that as it is not a high-level SPARK **API** like `df_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options ...`, then I think it should remain open, but would like to check. May be the SPARK env closes it automatically, but I think not. At the end of processing a close could be issued?

2. Using the HIVE Context means we do not need to open the connection every time - or is that not so? Then using a parquet or ORC table, then I presume would allow such an approach as performance is quite fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this simulation and connection remains open, so provided not in foreach,  it is not an issue performance-wise.

```
var counter = 0
do
  {
    counter = counter + 1
    val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "(select author from family) f ", connectionProperties)  
    dataframe_mysql.show

  } while (counter < 3)
```